# mesh array modifier with simple deform taper and curve modifier

Tags: modeling, scale

This mesh has an array modifier, simple deform taper modifier and a curve modifier.  I want it to scale along the curve as reference does? How would I go about this? Thanks
[image: horn scale issue]

Comment: can you post a picture of your modifier stack? what order are they in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could control the instance's radius with the curve's vertices radius, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or N panel, but it's still not exactly the result you're looking for:

[image]

Actually you could have a much more accurate result with a bezier curve which you'd give a bevel and a taper object:

[image]

Comment: creating the taper cure with a bezier curve is proving very difficult to control. Is there a simple method you used to create the one in the example?

Comment: it's not so complicated, maybe there's something you didn't understand? Actually to make mine I just duplicate the same curve several times. You may prefer to draw it with a mesh then convert to curve? Also you need to keep in mind that Blender takes into account the curve inclination on the Z axis and its position to its origin. Once you've drawn the taper profile, try to play with these 2 factors, inclination and position to origin.